# Adding and subtracting a system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I have this system of equations:

$$3a-7b=4d-9$$
$$-4c+10a=6b+7$$
$$-2a+3c-4d=10$$

The questions asks for the value of 
$$-10a-2b+2c$$

Now, initially I was trying to solve for a particular variable, but ended up getting nowhere. The solution explains the way to find the answer is by subtracting all the functions. So the line up all the variables to one side and then subtract:

$$3a-7b+0c-4d = -9$$
$$10a-6b-4c+0d=7$$
$$-2a+0b+3c-4d=10$$

And once they subtract all those three:

$$= -5a-1b+1c=-26$$
$$2(-5a-1b+1c=-26) = -10a-2b+2c = 2(-26) = -52$$

I understand their process clearly. However, I don't understand why it works? **How does adding or subtracting equations in a system equal to anything that is useful?** When you add or subtract equations in a system do you get a new line or is that a line that represents the entire system? **I guess my confusion is that I see all those three equations as lines, but when I mesh them all together I can't picture what results from that?**

EDIT:
So my questions are:

1. How does adding or subtracting equations in a system equal to anything that is useful?
2. When you add or subtract equations in a system do you get a new line or is that a line that represents the entire system?
3. I guess my confusion is that I see all those three equations as lines, but when I mesh them all together I can't picture what results from that? How is it consistent with the first three equations?
4. When would you use this?

Comment: You have four variables and three equations, so there are always going to be either no solutions or an infinite number of solutions. It is still possible to solve for the individual variables, but you'll need to use parameterize the solutions as there are an infinite number of them (eg. $a=\lambda, b=\lambda-4,...,\lambda\in\Bbb R$). Then you'll find that these parameters cancel each other out when you calculate the expression (as it's constant). Of course, this isn't the quickest way, but guarantees you reach the required solution.

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianElimination.html, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination

Comment: Adding and subtracting equations results in new equations that are as true as the original equations. The trick is to find the sequence of additions subtractions to find the result you are after.

Comment: $-52$ is the right result, what question do you have?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner edited my question

Comment: @Pablo The solution of a real system of linear equations with $n$ variables is some subspace of $\Bbb R^n$

Comment: Also, I'm not sure whether by "I see these equations as lines" you mean the linguistic "line" as in a line from Shakespeare or if you mean the geometric "line" such as the line $y=2x+1$ (in $\Bbb R^2$).  In actuality, the equation $3a-7b+0c-4d=-9$ represents a three-dimensional hyperplane in $\Bbb R^4$.  An example of a line in $\Bbb R^4$ would have looked more like $2 a = b - 1=3 c +1 = d$

Comment: The OP is correct. This exercise establishes nothing useful. It is a puzzle whose solution illustrates no general principle since it applies to this example alone.

Comment: Well.. the general approach would be to apply gaussian elimination, where you'll arrive at $b=\frac{97}{10}-a, c=4a-\frac{163}{10}$ and $d=\frac{5a}{2}-\frac{589}{40}$.  We can then word everything in the line in question in terms of $a$, namely $-10a-2b+2c=-10a-2(\frac{97}{10}-a)+2(4a-\frac{163}{10})$, then after some messy arithmetic find that all of the $a$'s cancel leaving you with just $-52$ as a final result.

Comment: @Pablo Lines in a 4 dimensional space are 3D hyperplanes, BTW. Anyway if $R=0$ and $S=0$ are convergent lines any linear combination like $hR+kS=0$ with h and k not simultaneously zero, is the equation of a line that passes through the intersection of the first two. If the coordinates are $3$ for instance $x+y-2z-6=0$ and $x-2y+z-3=0$ are non parallel planes and $h(x+y-2z-6)+k(x-2y+z-3)=0$ is the equation of a plane passing for the line of intersection of the two given planes